# how to display both id and value in dropdown list in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This is my code in my View

```
 {{ Form::label('supplier_list', 'Supplier', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
    {{ Form::select('supplier', $supplier_list, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

This is my code in controller

```
 $supplier_list = Supplier::lists('supplier_name', 'id');
```

My ouput is a Dropdown of SupplierName, what would I need is a Dropdown of displaying both SupplierName and ID, How to do it in laravel 4.2 ?

Comment: you mean you have to display name and ID both?

Comment: @vipulsorathiya Yes indeed

Comment: Finally found a solution.

$supplier_list = Supplier::select(DB::raw('concat (supplier_name," ",id) as supplier_name,id'))->lists('supplier_name', 'id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**In Controller**

```
 $supplier_list = Supplier::lists('supplier_name', 'id')->get();
```

**In Template**

```
<select  name="id" class="form-control">
     <option value="">Select Supplier Name</option>
     @foreach ($supplier_list as $key => $v)
         <option value="{!! $v['id'] !!}">{!! $v['supplier_name'] !!}{!! $v['id'] !!}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: This will work Thanks man but I think this is a much easier way 
$supplier_list = Supplier::select(DB::raw('concat (supplier_name," ",id) as supplier_name,id'))->lists('supplier_name', 'id');

Comment: $supplier_list = Supplier::select(DB::raw('concat (supplier_name," ",id) as supplier_name,id'))->lists('supplier_name', 'id');